# How to find the limit of the sequence $x_n = 0.1\underbrace{00 \ldots0}_{n}1$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Given a sequence, $$(x_n) = (0.101,0.1001,0.10001,\ldots)$$How do I proceed with finding the limit of this sequence? Note that I'm asking for a "method" to solve/find the limit.

---

The best I can come up with is write $x_n = 0.1\underbrace{00 \ldots0}_{n}1$ and "guess" that the limit should be $0.1$ and prove that

$$\left|0.1\underbrace{00 \ldots0}_{n}1 - 0.1\right|= 10^{-(n+1)} < \epsilon, \quad \forall \epsilon > 0$$

when $n≥m=\lfloor \log_{10}{\epsilon}+1 \rfloor+1$. But that being said, I want to know how to correctly and/or mathematically find the limit without just "guessing".

And how do I find out such limits in general, for instance when the sequence is something like $(0.101001, 0.10010001,0.1000100001, \ldots)$ where my $x_n = 0.1\underbrace{00 \ldots0}_{n}1\underbrace{00 \ldots 0}_{n+1}1$

Comment: Does it become clearer if you write it as $x_n = \frac{1}{10} + \left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^{n+2}$?

Comment: In general, there are no methods that work for all limits. That's what makes them interesting.

Comment: @MartinR Oh for the love of God, how did not see that?! Going with your comment, the second sequence I mention is simply just $x_n= \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{10^{n+2}} + \frac{1}{10^{2n+4}}$, right? Now I just look stupid asking this lol.

Comment: I think it's a good question. When teaching, we may just "see" what a sequence converges to, and expect students to do the same. It would be interesting to know a list of techniques that exist for finding limits without having an explicit equation for the $n^\mathrm{th}$ term. My first thought for your sequences is to observe that they are strictly decreasing and bounded below by 0.1. Then I check that there isn't a larger lower bound. But I'm not sure if you consider those observations as guesses.

Comment: @Joe I wouldn't consider that guessing, however for monotone convergence theorem to make sense, I'd need to show that $0.1$ is indeed the infimum, I'm not sure how I would do that rigorously?

Comment: Irrelevant comment: Is the ping feature broke? How do I ping someone with two words— i.e. first name and last name, to reply to them?

Comment: Without having an equation for the $n^\mathrm{th}$ term, there would need to be something in the definition of the sequence that allows you to prove that there isn't a larger lower bound. For example, without first writing down the equation for the second sequence, you can show straight from how you defined it that if $x\ge0.2$ it isn't a lower bound, and if $x=0.1d_2d_3\ldots$ with any $d_n\ne0$, then it isn't a lower bound because it'll be greater than the $n^\mathrm{th}$ term.

Answer (score 1):

Just write
$
x_n = 0.1\underbrace{00 \ldots0}_{n}1 = {1\over10} + {1\over 10^{n+2}}
$
and conclude $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n={1\over10}$.

For your second question write $y_n= 0.1\underbrace{00 \ldots0}_{n}1\underbrace{00 \ldots 0}_{n+1}1= {1\over10} + {1\over 10^{n+2}} + {1\over 10^{2n+4}}$ and conclude $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n={1\over10}$.

Answer (score 1):

**As "formally" as possible:**

You can express that the value of a decimal number of decimals $d_k$ is

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty d^k\cdot10^{-k},$$ and in this particular case

$$\begin{cases}d_1=d_{n+2}=1\\d_k=0,\forall k\ne1\land k\ne n+2\end{cases}$$

$$1\cdot10^{-1}+0\cdot10^{-2}+0\cdot10^{-3}+\cdots1\cdot10^{-n-2}+0\cdot10^{-n-3}+0\cdot10^{-n-4}+\cdots\\=10^{-1}+10^{-n-2}.$$

The limit follows easily (sum of a constant term and a decaying geometric sequence). The second case is not much harder.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is not an easy task to do. There are a few tricks we can use though, especially if we have a closed form representation for the elements.

For example, for the first example, we can write $x_n = 0.1 + 10^{-(n+2)}$. Then:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n &= \lim_{n\to \infty} (0.1 + 10^{-(n+2)}) \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} (0.1) + \lim_{n \to \infty} (10^{-(n+2)}) \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} (0.1) + 10^{-2} \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^n\right)
\end{align*} We know the limit of a constant sequence is just the constant, and the limit of $a^{n}$ as $n \to \infty$ where $|a| < 1$ is $0$, so we can simplify to just $0.1 + 0 = 0.1$.

For the second example you gave, we again look for a nice representation of $x_n$. What I see here is $x_n = 0.1 + 10^{-(n+2)} + 10^{-(2n+4)}$. Again, both of the second terms vanish in the limit, so we are left with just the constant part.

In general, it will be helpful to know some rules about how limits work. For instance, you should try to find out (and prove!) when it is valid to write things like:

- $\lim(a_n+b_n) = \lim(a_n) + \lim(b_n)$
- $\lim(a_n b_n) = \lim(a_n)\lim(b_n)$
- $\lim(f(a_n)) = f(\lim(a_n))$

where $a_n, b_n$ are sequences and $f$ is a function.